# Error on laravel vue inertia post method on share hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have trouble on laravel inertia  post method on share hosting ,  most of time post methods does worked well but sometimes it doesn't work and loading time too long and fail to submit data.

Comment: please provide your code or more data

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei, I built small pos service for shop with laravel inertia vue, most of time submit order is doing well but sometime it's happen like these error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.